# Azure Log Query show Null values

Tags: azure, logging, null, zero, azure-data-explorer

currently I am building a monitoring in Azure with log queries in diagrams.
This is working fine so far, but I have a problem. If I want to display the zero values in a diagram I get problems.
When I query for Count I only get values that contain data.

I have tried the following to output the zero values:

```
    customEvents
| where name == "GlobalHostHandleMessageError" and tolower(customDimensions.MessageType) in ("listmanager")
| where customDimensions.DeliveryCount == "10"
| project MessageType = customDimensions.MessageType, timestamp 
| summarize SumMessages=count() by tostring(MessageType), timestamp
| make-series count() default=0 on timestamp in range(ago(1d), now(), 1h) by MessageType
| mvexpand timestamp, count_
```

Unfortunately I can't display a chart after the "make-series" command. The following error is displayed:

```
FAILED TO CREATE VISUALIZATION
The Pie can't be created as you are missing a column of one of the following types: int, long, decimal or real
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output for mvexpand is always a dynamically typed column. Try changing the last line to:
`mvexpand timestamp, tolong(count_)`.

Comment: The conversion from dynamic to long should be using the following syntax:

| mv-expand Timestamp to typeof(datetime ), count_ to typeof(long)

Comment: Thank you very much again for supporting me on this case!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer! That worked so far.
My diagram looks like this now:

[image]

But the next problem is when there is no data it looks like the following. Its not possible to show only zero data to put that in a diagram so that it looks like something like this:

[image]

When there is no data my results looking like the following picture:

[image]

Is it even possible to get results with count on zero?

I only getting this:

[image]

Regards

Comment: Do you know what part of the query results in no data? E.g. `| where customDimensions.DeliveryCount == "10"` filters out everything. It isn't clear to me what causes there to be 0 results and therefore what the expected behavior should be.